# How do I prove that that $n \geq \log_2(n) ^{(\log_2(\log_2(n))}$ as n becomes large?

Tags: computational-complexity

More specifically, I am trying to show that the asymptotic complexity of a problem with that has the bounds $\Theta(\log{2}(n) ^{(\log_2(\log_2(n))})$ is less than that of a problem with the bounds $\Theta(n)$.

I tried to use L'Hospital's rule but the derivatives become too complicated for that to be a good solution. I suspect that there may be a substitution that I can make, but if there is I cannot see what it is.

Edit: I originally stated that the log term was greater, which is clearly an error.

[image]

Comment: take $\log_2(\cdot)$ from both sides.

Comment: Sure that this inequality holds for large $n$ ? numerical calculations indicate the opposite inequality. For example, for $\large n=10^{10^5}$, I get $1.87\cdot 10^{101}$, which is much smaller

Comment: @Peter: I was wrong before; I misinterpreted the question. Sorry :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you mean the inequality should be the other way around ? Take $ \log_2 $ of the inequality
\begin{eqnarray*}
\log_2 (n) \leq \left( \log_2( \log_2 (n)) \right)^2
\end{eqnarray*}
Now let $n=2^{2^N}$ and we get
\begin{eqnarray*}
2^N \leq N^2
\end{eqnarray*}
which is obviously false for large $N$

Comment: What is ? at the end?

Comment: I think "which is obviously false for large $N$" is better than "?".

Answer (score 1):

The inequality goes the wrong way.
$$(\log_2 n)^{\log_2 \log_2 n} = 2^{(\log_2 \log_2 n)^2}$$ 
while
$$n = 2^{\log_2 n}$$
Now $\log_2 t = o(t^\alpha)$ for any $\alpha>0$ as $t \to \infty$.
Taking $t = \log_2 n$ we have $\log_2 \log_2 n = o((\log_2 n)^{1/2})$
and $(\log_2 \log_2 n)^2 = o(\log_2 n)$.